# Malloc for struct in C

Tags: c, struct, malloc

so I have to do a c program that reads a text file, stores it in a struct with an extra value (the average) and output the struct with fread into a new struct. However the information isnt going anywhere. I'm almost positive its the malloc don't know how to allocate the proper amount of memory (C++ and Java kinda spoiled me there)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct student {
    int id;
    float marks [10];
    float gpa;
} Student;

int main (){
    FILE *inFile, *bin;
    int i, sum, sLength;
    char input[45];
    char newLine;
    inFile = fopen ("Assign6.dat","r");
    bin = fopen ("Assign6out.dat","wb+");
    Student current;

//  while (!feof(inFile)){
        sum = 0;
        fgets (input,sizeof(input), inFile);
        sLength = strlen(input);
        sscanf (input, "%d\n", &(current.id));
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            sscanf (input, "%lf", &(current.marks[i]));
            sum += current.marks[i];
        }
        current.gpa = sum / 6;
        fwrite (&current, sizeof (Student), 1, bin);

//  }
    fclose(inFile);
    Student newer;
    fseek (bin, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread (&newer, 1, sizeof(Student), bin);
    fclose(bin);
    printf( "%d, %.1lf\n", newer.id, newer.marks[0]);
}
```

So the input file is this

```
122456 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0
```

and the output is

```
122456, 0.0
```

can anyone help me on this please? I looked around but couldn't really find anything that fit for me.

First Post so be nice please!

Comment: What `malloc()`? I don't see a call to `malloc()` anywhere.

Comment: If the "information isn't going anywhere", what is this output of which you speak?

Comment: It's good you commented out the `while (!feof(inFile))` loop, because that loop would not work as you expected. That's because the `EOF` flag isn't set until you try to read from beyond the end of the file. What you should do is e.g. `while (fgets(...) != NULL)`.

Comment: Im thinking I might need to add it in somewhere? right now im trying to use sizeof to go by. Im fairly sure i need to Malloc the struct somehow before reading and writing. 

Now the output is jsut testing to see if the read and write worked. as you can see it takes the identifier but no marks make it into the struct

Comment: also I've already tested that while loop for inputting and I can confirm it does input the information correctly

Comment: Why would you need to dynamically allocate the structure? By declaring it as a local variable on the stack it's already allocated for you by the compiler.

Comment: Oh, and I assume you have verified that you read the data correctly (e.g. by having a `printf` statement before the `fwrite`)?

Comment: And regarding the loop, if you keep it the way you have it now then the last entry will be duplicated.

Comment: when I get the size of the struct its only 96. however the size of 1 double is much bigger than that right? so Im thinking the sizes aren't lining up because of the array I have in there. and yes I have confirmed the fwrite works.

Comment: The structure in the question should be 48 bytes. If it's 96 then you are using `double` and not `float` (plus what seems like 4 bytes of padding).

Comment: oh ya I forgot i made that change. I switched them recently from double to float

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is most likely due to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior): The structure member `marks` is an array of `float`, but you try to parse the values from the text file using the format `"%lf"` which expects a pointer to a *`double`*. A pointer to a `float` is not the same as a pointer to a `double`.

Change the `sscanf` format to `"%f"` and it should work better.

I recommend you read [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), it has a very good table of the different formats and what argument they expect.

Comment: ya I forgot i changed from doubles to float. However, after making this change it didn't change the result. Also I shall read that article now